# How do I access every other element in a list while using the elements in the original order?

Tags: python, list, loops

Sorry for the confusing question. I have a list called switch that contains randomly chosen numbers between 10 and 30. I am trying to use these numbers in the following function (this is just the start):

```
def rewardfunc(y, switch):
   left_reward = []
   right_reward = []
   for x in range(switch[0]):
      left_reward.append(prob(y))
      right_reward.append(prob(1-y))
   for x in range(switch[1]):
      left_reward.append(prob(1-y))
      right_reward.append(prob(y))
   for x in range(switch[2]):
      left_reward.append(prob(y))
      right_reward.append(prob(1-y))
   for x in range(switch[3]):
      left_reward.append(prob(1-y))
      right_reward.append(prob(y))
```

In this function, every number in switch is used to define a block of trials, but every other number defines a different kind block. So, my problem is how do I use every number in switch in order, while using every other number for a different task? Currently, I'm writing it out as for x in range((switch[0]))... is there a way to do this in a shorter form?

Hope my question makes sense. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, x in enumerate(switch):
    for _ in range(x):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            left_reward.append(prob(y))
            right_reward.append(prob(1-y))
        else: 
            left_reward.append(prob(1-y))
            right_reward.append(prob(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, just swap references to `left_reward` and `right_reward`. Something like

```
def rewardfunc(y, switch):
   l = left_reward = []
   r = right_reward = []
   for x1 in switch:
       for x2 in x1:
           l.append(prob(y))
           r.append(prob(1-y))
       l, r = r, l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a fan of comprehensions:

```
left_reward = [prob(1-y if i % 2 else y) for i in range(len(switch))]
right_reward = [prob(y if i % 2 else 1-y) for i in range(len(switch))]
```

If `prob(e)` is expensive at all then consider precalculating:

```
prob_y, prob_inv_y = prob(y), prob(1-y)
left_reward = [prob_inv_y if i % 2 else prob_y for i in range(len(switch))]
right_reward = [prob_y if i % 2 else prob_inv_y for i in range(len(switch))]
```